# Regular Expression to get certain colon-delimited fields

Tags: .net, regex

I need to extract the string

```
MAC:BFEBFBFF000006FB00:1E:37:54:AE:C8
```

out of

```
ADMIN:1EXT:0NOR:0OUT:1PRI:1BAT:1MOD:1MAC:BFEBFBFF000006FB00:1E:37:54:AE:C8
```

The regular expression i use is

```
(MAC:[A-Z0-9]{10})+
```

But still i do not get the intended result

Answer (score 3):

`(MAC:[A-Z0-9:]+)` will match: `MAC:BFEBFBFF000006FB00:1E:37:54:AE:C8`.

`(MAC:[A-Z0-9]+)` will match: `MAC:BFEBFBFF000006FB00`.

Answer (score 2):

```
(MAC:(([A-F0-9]+:*)))
```

Mac address are in hexadecimal characters...so it's A-F and not A-Z.

PS: I've tested the expression.

Comment: That is a good point! I just took for granted that the OP meant A-Z.

Answer (score 1):

The expression states that you will have multiple sequences of 10 characters of [A-Z0-9] which isn't the case four your desired string.

Your regex matches

```
MAC:BFEBFBFF00
```

If the input is like your example, you could use a simple regex like this

```
MAC:[A-F0-9:]+
```

Otherwise, you could do something like this if you want to be very specific

```
MAC:[A-F0-9]{18}(:[A-Z0-9]{2}){5}
```

As pointed out by The Elite Gentleman you can get by using just A-F, if you're looking for hex numbers.